# Difference in compass, gyroscope and GPS : Android vs iOs in Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, sensors, android-sensors

I developed an iOS AR app with Unity.
It shows Points Of Interests in a city : like foursquare. 
This is how it works (roughly) :

- Position of the user by GPS.
- Script that orientates the camera : using the gyroscope and the compass altogether.

When I try to adapt it to Android I got bad results. Like real bad. 
I know that not all Android phones have a gyroscope, I'll exclude them from DL the app.
But for those who have Gyroscope and compass it should work almost the same...

Do someone know the fondamental differences that could cause that ? Do I have to Write native plugins ?

Thank you guys !
Quentin

Comment: if you want to use all three things and making your complete logic dependent upon them then, you surely need to provide alternative if any one feature is not available

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will indeed provide an alternative lower quality system. But in the case where all 3 of this devices are up, it doesn't work either.

Comment: so definitely there is limitation but almost any smartphone support GPS

Comment: Yep, and I tested on a S7. Gyroscope is up, compass is up. and the result are nonsense.

Comment: nonsense what kind of ?

Comment: Gyroscope / compass rotation seems to not work at all. it move really slowly compare to the device rotation. The orientation is good but the movement is   so slow. thank you for you answers mate